# Regular expression: only numbers and -, no characters, spaces or other special characters

Tags: regex, google-docs

I have a field in Google Docs for phone numbers and want to make sure that all phone numbers entered have the format

012345-67890

Can anybody help me on writing the right REGEX for this? I then plan to use this as a rule for the data validation.

Kind regards!
Mike

Comment: so 0723467642 is not a phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `/^[0-9]{6}[-][0-9]{5}$/`

#### Matched:

```
012345-67890
```

#### Not matched:

```
12345-67890
12345-678901
01234567890
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great basis. As the number of digits doesn't matter, I slightly changed the REGEX and got this to work now: =regexmatch(G674;"^[0-9]+[-][0-9]")